# What are my compact CNC milling machine options for stone carving?

Tags: tools, materials, stone

I am looking for suggestions about a small and compact CNC milling machine to sculpt decorative figures in metal and stone plates. I have no experience with such machines (I once saw an industrial one using high pressure water to cut through marble, but it's beyond my needs, budget and expertise), but I would not need a professional level machine, just a hobby level one with basic functionalities

I would like to know the following information:

- suggestions for resellers and products
- expected price
- expected maintenance
- tips for usage and precautions

Comment: FYI... Computer numerical control (CNC) milling machine - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milling_machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch site [like hobbycnc](http://www.hobbycnc.com/) that sell plans and parts to build your own hobby cnc.  Here's a [site that sells a kit](http://buildyourcnc.com/blackToe2x4v40.aspx).  Looks pretty neat actually...now I know what I want for Christmas!

**Update**:
Just found the [Torchmate](http://torchmate.com/resource_center/featured_product_videos/) series.  They have a [Torchmate 2x2](http://torchmate.com/products/torchmate_2x2/) version starting at $3000.

Comment: Searching for "miniature hobbyist milling machine" also turned up this site (~$500): http://www.micromark.com/Machine-Tools.html but that one is not computer controlled.

Comment: Here is one that is computer controlled (~$2500): http://www.sherline.com/CNCprices.htm

Comment: @Jeff : I'm unable to understand if the sherline one is able to dig through stone or metal

Comment: @Stefano : I just added the Torchmate system. This seems promising.

Answer (score 3):

micRo - ~[$2000](http://www.lumenlab.com/d/micro) (Need to buy a few pieces). This thing looks really nice, but has a small work area. The guy that makes them is fanatical about quality hobby equipment. http://lumenlab.com

DIY - ~[$750](http://buildyourcnc.com/billmaterials.aspx). If you want to take the DIY approach and have a larger work area, pick up a copy of [Build Your Own CNC Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224894). The [companion website](http://buildyourcnc.com/) literally has videos of the guy making the machine on a kitchen table with hand tools. I'm half way through the book and it appears surprisingly straight forward.